# Change color for each word in text without js

Tags: html, css

I want to change the color for some text.

Example:
"hello guys, i am a girl".
1: "hello", "i", "a" is green
2: "guys", "am" and "girl" is grey.

Can I do it?
Please do not use html tag insert to word, something like this :

```
<p><span class="green">hello</span> <span class="grey">guys</span>, <span class="green">i</span> <span class="grey">am</span> <span class="green">a</span> <span class="grey">girl</span>
```

I just want `<p>hello guys, i am a girl</p>` and css for this.
Thank you

Comment: It is not possible with pure css, but is is easy with js.

Comment: If you want to avoid JS then span with some class needs to be given, so that you can attach styles to the respective classes

Answer (score 1):

Without using JavaScript or additional markup, this is not possible with CSS alone.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: The question being asked is whether this is possible without JavaScript or additional markup (stated in the question). The answer is that it is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

```
span:nth-of-type(odd) {
color:green;
}

span:nth-of-type(even) {
color:red;
}
```

if you don't want it by even/odd words, just change it to a number like this:

```
 span:nth-of-type(1) {
 color:green;
  }
```

Comment: or just `p{ color: green; } span:nth-of-type(even){ color: red; }`

Comment: I think the OP wants to *not* use `<span>` elements: "Please do not use html tag insert to word". I could be wrong.